# Count triangle area - working as vars but not wrapped as a function

Tags: javascript, function, math, math.sqrt

A noob question. I am playing with http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-basic-exercises.php#EDITOR javascript exercises. Exercise number 4. Count the area of a triangle.

Why this works:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 6;
var c = 7;
var p = (a+b+c) / 2;
var p1 = (p * (p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
var poleA = Math.sqrt(p1);
console.log(poleA);
```

And this does not (console gives error):

```
function () {
var a = 5;
var b = 6;
var c = 7;
var p = (a+b+c) / 2;
var p1 = (p * (p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
var poleA = Math.sqrt(p1);
}
console.log(poleA);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because `poleA` is declared inside the function (in second case) and it does not exists in `window` namespace.

Try to remove `var` from `poleA`so it will become a global variable thus accessible outside of method scope.